# How to correctly map a Polygon with a SRID with postgis and Hibernate Spatial 5.2

Tags: java, postgis, hibernate-spatial

I have an java entity class with a column that is annotated as follows:

```
@Column(name = "extent", columnDefinition = "geometry(Polygon,4326)")
private Polygon extent;
```

When I tested this, I get an error message telling me that the SRID is missing.
It makes sense because a Polygon does not have any associated coordinate referenced system (CRS), and removing the CRS fixes the issue.

Is there a different way this column can be accessed via Hibernate while retaining the SRID information? I cannot find any examples anywhere that talk about this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
public final static int SRID = 4326;    
Polygon polygon = geometryFactory.createPolygon(shellCoordinates.stream().toArray(n -> new Coordinate[n]));
polygon.setSRID(SRID);
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of the code. pasting some code in an anwser wont help much

Comment: Basically code is converting an array of Coordinates to a type Polygon type. setSRID is explicity setting the SRID as sometimes within out hibernate column defintion we omit the SRID and thats required https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/GeometryFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Polygon has a setSRID(int) method with which to set the SRID. Duh!